# Why STDIN does not quit with break?

Tags: c, unix, stdin

```
char c;

while (read(0, &c, 1))
{
    if(c == '\n')
        break;
}
```

This is part of my program, that I thought it should be quit when I type Enter.

But it doesn't work.

Simillarly,

```
int line = 3;
char c;

while (read(0, &c, 1))
{
    line--;
    if (line == 0)
       break ;
}
```

This code doesn't works either.
Why? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Debugging help : Keep a debug log inside `while` loop & see whether its entered into loop or not, if yes print the `line` value. for e.g `printf("inside while loop <%c>  <%u> \n", c, line);` if `c` is declared as `char` type.

Comment: You do not provide enough context with your piece of code. Try to provide a minimal working example. We need to see how you declared the variable c, etc...

Comment: You would make your code more clear by using STDIN_FILENO instead of 0. include <unistd.h>

Comment: You should also consider that stdin might be line buffered, consider that what it means to type an enter on the keyboard.

Comment: Does your return key return `\n`? It could be `\r` as well. "Idiot Debugging" will help you with that -- see @Achal's comment above.

Comment: `while (read(0, &c, 1) == 1)`

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: @usr2564301: The question is tagged Unix and is using a Unix `read` call. The “return key” does not “return” `\n` or `\r`. It is interpreted by system and terminal software, and a `\n` is placed in the stream by that software. Unix does not use `\r` for this.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: Line buffering would result in the behavior OP is expecting, not interfere with it.

Comment: Your second set of code works when I wrap it in a `main` function and include `<unistd.h>`. If it does not work for you, you should provide a [mre].